# for loop inside a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'm trying to write a script in python to make my job easier.
I need to use `os.system` to call some functions to an external software.

Is there a way to insert a for loop inside this string, without having to write `obs_dir[n]` every time??

```
import os
obs_dir = ['18185','18186','18187','19926','19987','19994','19995','20045','20046','20081']
xid = ['src21']
i=0

os.system("pset combine_spectra src_arfs=/"
          + obs_dir[0] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[0] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[1] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[1] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[2] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[2] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[3] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[3] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[4] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[4] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[5] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[5] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[6] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[6] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[7] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[7] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[8] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[8] + "_spectrum.arf,"
          + "/" + obs_dir[9] + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + obs_dir[9] + "_spectrum.arf")
```

Comment: _insert a for loop inside this string..._ You mean a loop _around_ the string

Comment: I need to run `os.system(...)` only once.

Comment: Make the string first, then use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the required command by first iterating over the list(obs_dir) and forming the string.

**Ex:**

```
import os
obs_dir = ['18185','18186','18187','19926','19987','19994','19995','20045','20046','20081']
xid = ['src21']


s = "pset combine_spectra src_arfs="
for i in obs_dir:
    s += "/{0}/{1}_{0}_spectrum.arf, ".format(i, xid[0])

s = s.strip().rstrip(',')
print s
#os.system(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you want

```js
import os
obs_dir = ['18185','18186','18187','19926','19987','19994','19995','20045','20046','20081']
xid = ['src21']

str_cmd = "pset combine_spectra src_arfs=" + obs_dir[0]
separator = ""
for dir in obs_dir
  str_cmd + =  separator + "/" + dir + "/" + xid[i] + "_" + dir + "_spectrum.arf"
  separator = ","
  
os.system(str_cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `xid[i]`, but no `i`, so using `xid[0]`,

```
"/{}/{}_{}_spectrum.arf".format(obs_dir[1],xid[0],obs_dir[1])
```

gives

```
'/18186/src21_18186_spectrum.arf'
```

So, `format` helps.
Also, `join` will help join these into a comma separated string:

```
",".join(['a', 'b'])
```

gives

```
'a,b'
```

Joining this together you get

```
s = ",".join(["/{}/{}_{}_spectrum.arf".format(o,xid[0],o) for o in obs_dir])
```

giving the parameter(s) you want

```
'/18185/src21_18185_spectrum.arf,/18186/src21_18186_spectrum.arf,/18187/src21_18g187_spectrum.arf,/19926/src21_19926_spectrum.arf,/19987/src21_19987_spectrum.arfg,/19994/src21_19994_spectrum.arf,/19995/src21_19995_spectrum.arf,/20045/src21_20g045_spectrum.arf,/20046/src21_20046_spectrum.arf,/20081/src21_20081_spectrum.arfg'
```

without a spare `','` on the end.

Then use it

```
os.system("pset combine_spectra src_arfs=" + s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in the string, but we can build the string using features like list comprehension (in this case, a generator expression) and string joining:

```
obs_dir = ['18185','18186','18187','19926','19987','19994','19995','20045','20046','20081']
xid = ['src21']
i = 0

print("pset combine_spectra src_arfs=" +
    ",".join("/{0}/{1}_{0}_spectrum.arf".format(n,xid[i])
             for n in obs_dir))
```